# Transition between background img with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, background, jquery-animate, transition

I have the following JS to change background on my website when I click on button

I want animate the transition between these 2 backgrounds.
How can I do this?

```js
var ImageOne = true;
var UrlOne = "https://s24.postimg.org/itrww7ovp/capanaraeditada.png";
var UrlTwo = "https://s27.postimg.org/wylbf2t83/capanara.jpg";

function SwitchImage() {
  if (ImageOne) {
    ImageOne = false;
    UpdateBackground(UrlTwo);

  } else {
    ImageOne = true;
    UpdateBackground(UrlOne);

  }
}


function UpdateBackground(Url) {
  $("body").css("background", "url(" + Url + ") no-repeat center center scroll");
  $("body").css("-webkit-background-size", "cover");
  $("body").css("-moz-background-size", "cover");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="SwitchImage();">LUZ</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your `UpdateBackground`-Funtion:

```
$("body").css("transition", "background 1s");
```

The CSS property `transition` defines the time which should elapse between changes on other CSS properties. With the `background` in front of the `1s` here you say, that this second should just be applied on the background property.

That's just the top of the iceberg, you can do really cool things. Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) link for more information and the complete syntax.